# How to extract a file name from its path in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code, where I am opening a file for extracting data. I am currently using following code; I want to extract the file name from the path and store it in a particular range. This the code:

```
FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xls")
If FilePath <> False Then
Range("D6").Value = FilePath
file = Range("D6").Value
Range("D6").Clear
End If
```

Comment: You say "I want to extract the file name from the path and store it in a particular range" but then you clear D6. So do you want to do something with `file = Range("D6).value` later in your code **and** you want D6 to have just the file name without its path?

Comment: Yes exactly, I used this and it worked fine
strName = Right(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - InStrRev(FilePath, "\"))

then I assigned the strName to a Range and used the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

If FilePath <> False Then
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(FilePath)

    If Not objFile Is Nothing Then
        FileName = objFile.Name
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way:

```
FileName = Mid$(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") + 1, Len(FilePath))
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
Public Function ExtractFileName(ByVal strFullName As String) As String

Dim p As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer

i = 1
Do
    p = InStr(i, strFullName, "\", 1)
    If p = 0 Then Exit Do
    s = p
    i = p + 1
Loop
s = s + 1
ExtractFileName = Mid(strFullName, s, Len(strFullName))

End Function        'ExtractFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want various version of the path and file names, here's what I would suggest:

```
Sub LookupFileNames()
  Dim FilePath As String, FileOnly As String, PathOnly As String, ExtOnly As String, NameOnly As String

  FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
  NameOnly = Left(FileOnly, InStr(1, FileOnly, ".") - 1)
  ExtOnly = Right(FileOnly, Len(FileOnly) - InStr(1, FileOnly, "."))
  PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))

  MsgBox "Full Name: " & FilePath & vbLf & "File Name: " & FileOnly & vbLf & "File Name w/o Ext: " & NameOnly & vbLf & "File Ext: " & ExtOnly & vbLf & "File Path: " & PathOnly

End Sub
```