# VBA: Add to a UserForm's Title with current text already as caption

Tags: vba, userform

Good Evening,

I am having trouble with some VBA code. I need the add the Userform's Caption, with text already in place. This is for a application I'm writing which opens a file, and once the file has been opened, it will add the file name to the end of the UserForm's caption. For example:

Program Name: [File Name]

I wouldn't where to start really, which is why I'm here, but I think it might be something like

```
UserForm1.caption = "Program Name" + file.name
```

I don't know if this is really possible, but I would greatly appreciate some help

Cheers

Comment: Did you try that?  What happened?

Comment: It's  not exact code, and I know that it's wrong because I haven't addressed the right controls in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it' possible. I think a couple more steps needed

On open of application

logic example / not code:

```
Pub WriteFileName ()

Range("A:10")
End Sub
```

For the above, adaptable code example here : [How to extract a file name from its path in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32066081/3138260)

Then write another macro reading that cell range as string
to your UserForm.Caption object i.e ="string" + range.("A10")

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation yet, I'm new. But I will when I reach 15 rep. Thank you again.